# Text in circular Canvas in the center of the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

the text in the canvas is not appearing showing any text using script.
if is use ctx.fillText it shows nothing.
this code did not work please correct it.
if we comment these lines in the below given code then only the code work.

```
//ctx.font(30px Arial);
//ctx.fillText(Hello World,10,5);
```

plz check and answer,

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        canvas: {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -250px;
            margin-top: -100px;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas height="300" width="500" id="canvas"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var centerX = canvas.width/2;
        var centerY = canvas.height/2;
        var radius = 100;
        ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,2*Math.PI,false);
        ctx.font(30px Arial);
        ctx.fillText(Hello World,10,5);
        ctx.fillStyle='teal';
        ctx.fill();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open your console (hit F12). You've got a few syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,5);
```

You missed the quotes. Without quotes that's a refference to a variable/object. Basic programming skills...

Comment: in addition to that: `ctx.font()` is also used wrongly, should be `ctx.font = "30px arial";`

Comment: @K3N you're right. I missed that line.